# What is the easiest way to extract a string from an android xml layout file to a strings.xml file?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

Within Eclipse I navigate to the Refactor option in the context menu but it cannot be selected when I right click the string selection.

Comment: No idea about eclipse but intellij idea does it with its refactorings :)

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. You want to open the appropriate string when you click on the reference string in XML layout file?

Comment: I want Eclipse to generate a string from the layout xml file to the strings.xml file

Comment: This isn't really how you use string.xml

Comment: I recently read on some tutorial that there was a way to do it by a keyboard shorcut I'll post it as soon as I find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> on the String and then "Extract Android String".

Answer (score 1):

Found it: **ALT + SHIFT + A, S = Extract Android string to strings.xml file**